# Cannot initialize Redux mock store

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, redux, mocking, redux-mock-store

I am trying to use `redux-mock-store` as per documentation

```
import React from 'react'
import Enzyme from 'enzyme'
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16'
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store'

import App from '.'
import rootReducer from '../../store/reducers'

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() })

describe('The App container', () => {
    let store
    const mockStore = configureStore()

    beforeEach(() => store = mockStore(rootReducer))

    it('renders without crashing', () => {
        const tree = Enzyme.shallow(<App store={store} />)
        expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot()
    })
})
```

Problem is, I get the following errors:

> The previous state received by the reducer is of unexpected type. Expected argument to be an instance of Immutable.Collection or Immutable.Record with the following properties:

As well as:

> TypeError: inputState.withMutations is not a function

**Should I not be including the `rootReducer`?**

**Is there a better way to initialize the mock store?**

---

**Edit:** I tried also to use `initialState` to start the store, but no go:

```
import React from 'react'
import Enzyme from 'enzyme'
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16'
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store'

import App from '.'

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() })

describe('The App container', () => {
    let store
    const mockStore = configureStore()
    const initialState = {}

    beforeEach(() => store = mockStore(initialState))

    it('renders without crashing', () => {
        const tree = Enzyme.shallow(<App store={store} />)
        expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot()
    })
})
```

> ● The App container › renders without crashing
>
> TypeError: state.get is not a function

Comment: Looking at the docs, shouldn't you be passing in initialState instead of rootReducer?  Or an object of some kind?

Comment: Yeah, when I tried using initialState I get `store.getState is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

You should mount your component wrapped in a `Provider`:

```
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'

// ...store configuration

const tree = Enzyme.mount(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  <Provider>
)

// ... assertions
```

`shallow` also has a second parameter for passing context but I am not sure if it is woking with redux store.

Comment: It's a shame I didn't make a sandbox link. I don't know if this would have solved my issue